# Setting num-lock based on time

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, numlock

I have a laptop that I take to work. At home, I have an external keyboard so I usually key num-lock on. At work, I want num lock to be off.

Is there a way to 'schedule' num lock on/of behavior? 9am onwards, num lock should be off by default whenever I switch it on. 7pm onwards, it should be on by default.

:edit: Another approach that was suggested in comments was to set the numlock based on existence of an external keyboard. If you have an external keyboard connected, set numlock on. Otherwise set it off.

Any hints how I can accomplish this on linux (ubuntu 12.04)?

Comment: It looks more like you want the NumLock status to depend on *presence of external keyboard*, not on a specific time...

Comment: That sounds like a better idea. Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer from Serge, I was able to come up with something. I wrote a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=`lsusb | grep PS/2 | wc -l`

if [ $x -eq '1' ]
then
    numlockx on
else
    numlockx off
fi
```

This works for my machine - you might have to modify it a bit to suit yours. But it lists all USB devices connected. If there's a PS/2 connector (I use one), there will be a USB device for it. Based on it's presence, I turn numlock on/off.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the initial goal with `numlockx` command. First, make sure it is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Then follow [Adding Program To Session Startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) instructions to add the following command:

```
date +%H|grep -Eq '^(09|1[0-8])$' && numlockx off || numlockx on
```